# Assigning matrix rows with particular indices

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

I am porting some code from `Matlab` to `Armadillo` and am stuck at a simple step. I am finding all the indices of a vector `res` on the basis of a condition and then want to store all the rows of a matrix `Pts` corresponding to the condition.

So what it is in matlab

```
ifAny = find(res < lim);
Pts = Pts(ifAny,:);
```

In Armadillo -

```
arma::uvec ifAny = arma::find(﻿﻿res < lim);
// elem gives only the single column
// Pts = Pts.elem(ifAny);
```

Comment: Not an armadillo expert, but is `Pts = Pts.rows(ifAny);` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Submatrix view section of Armadillo's API documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat), the `X.rows(vector_of_row_indices)` would extract the selected set of non-contiguous rows in the provided `vector_of_row_indices` from the matrix `X`.

Thus in your case, to obtain a result equivalent to `Pts = Pts(ifAny,:)` of Matlab, you can use :

```
Pts = Pts.rows(ifAny);
```